# Restart completed jobs in spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

We are using spring batch version
<spring.batch.version>5.0.0</spring.batch.version>

Code:

```
    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
        .addLong("run.id", 1L, false)
        .addString(SchedulerConstants.TENANTID_CONTEXT, "Tenant1")
        .toJobParameters();
      jobExecution = SchedulerLauncher.run(inferenceJob, jobParameters);
```

We have jobs created with job param as Tenant1, Tenant2 . tenantN etc. which is triggered periodically.

Use case is to restart the job once its completed.
We cant add current timestamp etc, as its multi process application, as we dont want it run in every process.

Whats the better way to restart the completed jobs

Restarting using job param , didnt help much.

Comment: Hey suchin, I haven't tested this thoroughly, so hopefully someone else will have a more definitive answer for you, but one solution I'm exploring is to simply run the job again with different parameters. Maybe you are saying that you tried that already? In my case I'm just adding a "time" parameter, which is innocuous, but should make it be seen as a new job and therefore restarted.

Comment: hi @NathanLively
Yes, with time parameter it will work but if any case same jobs can run parallel , for example in case multi process application. We should run the job only when its completed.